# Read only Spring Boot App- NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type available: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

I'm creating a read only REST API using Spring Boot 2.7 and Java 19

I followed the idea posted here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-read-only-repository

I've created a read only generic repository:

```
package com.scope.mdm.domain;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
    List<T> findAll();
}
```

This is a simplify view of the entity definition:

```
package com.scope.mdm.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;

@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "v_LegalEntity", schema = "entity_reference")
public class LegalEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LegalEntityId")
    Integer legalEntityId;
    @Column(name = "SO_Id")
    String soId;
    @Column(name = "Source_LegalEntityId")
```

I implemented a read only repository as follows:

```
package com.scope.mdm.domain;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface LegalEntityReadOnlyRepository extends ReadOnlyRepository<LegalEntity, Integer> {

    // Fetch legal entities by Scope One Id
    Optional<LegalEntity> findBySoId(String soId);

    // Fetch legal entities by its data source provided ID
    LegalEntity findByLegalEntityId(String legalEntityId);

    // Legal entities containing the name
    List<LegalEntity> findByLegalEntityNameLike(String legalEntityName);

}
```

This is the controller:

```
package com.scope.mdm.web;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.scope.mdm.domain.LegalEntity;
import com.scope.mdm.domain.LegalEntityReadOnlyRepository;

@RestController
public class LegalEntityController {
    @Autowired
    private LegalEntityReadOnlyRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/legalEntities", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<LegalEntity> getLegalEntity() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I want to do a simple unit test like this:

```
package com.scope.mdm;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import com.scope.mdm.domain.LegalEntityReadOnlyRepository;
import com.scope.mdm.domain.LegalEntityRepository;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

@SpringBootTest(classes = mdmWebAPIApplication.class)
public class legalEntitySearchTest {
    @Autowired
    private LegalEntityRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    private LegalEntityReadOnlyRepository repositoryReadOnly;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(repositoryReadOnly);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(repository);
    }
```

}

When running the test from VSCODE I get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.scope.mdm.domain.LegalEntityReadOnlyRepository' available:
> expected single matching bean but found 2:
> legalEntityRepository,legalEntityReadOnlyRepository

I tried with the @Qualifier annotation to explicitly specify the bean but the result is the same.

Comment: What does your `LegalEntityRepository` look like? The error isn't wrong so I suspect you did something like `extends LegalEntityReadOnlyRepository, CrudRepository`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what the article I referenced above suggests. I want to have a read-only resource "LegalEntity" but for unit test I want to create new LegalEntity instances, therefore a read-only repository is created in "main" and another repository which extends CrudRepository (to generate, i.e., the save functionality) in the "test" scope.

Comment: Which is wrong. You shouldn't extend that readonly interface. As that will, as the error tells you, result in 2 beans implementing this interface. Instead you should **only extend `CrudRepository`**.

Comment: @M.Deinum I remove the inheritance from LegalEntityReadOnlyRepository and extend only from CrudRepository as suggested and now is working.